# How do I mark a full day as "out of office" in Google Calendars?

Tags: google-calendar

In Google Calendar, I see how to mark time as out of office, and how to create an all day event. But how do I mark a full day as out of office?

Comment: It's 2020 and there still seems to be no clean way to do this. Maybe, as an American company, the idea of an employee having a full day off is alien to them?

Comment: I can't believe this feature does not exist. How can this be missing? If a create a normal entry, I can only choose between busy or available, not away.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like there is no option to select all day. However, you could select the appropriate range for it - start of the day and the start of the new day. 
Please see an example on the screenshot:
[image: OOO - All day]

Answer (score -1):

As of 2019, please try this:

1. Use the '+ Create' button above the mini calendar
2. Select 'More Options'
3. Check 'Add day' box to remove times, leaving dates
4. Complete the remaining details as usual and Save

Comment: That makes an event, instead of marking the time as out of office. A minor difference in most use cases... but the calendar will show it differently.